# Spring-Security-UI: Use domain model constraints for validation

Tags: grails, user-interface, spring-security

I want to use the constraints of my User domain model instead of the one provided by the RegisterCommand. Is it possible to modify it in a way that they are used? I already have custom views and controller for register.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom Controller you could just create your own command object for the validation and use the Grails 2.0 [importFrom](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html#sharingConstraints) ability in its `constraints` block.  If it must be an instance of `RegisterCommand`, just create a subclass and override the `constraints` in the subclass with `importFrom`.